# After the button is clicked, the statement will not be executed down and the timeout will not be reported

Tags: selenium

When I manipulate the driver to click a button, the event of this button is to use showModalDialog to open a new window, the program will no longer proceed down, and will always stay on the statement of clicking the button, even if I set set_page_load_timeout, even I use multithreading to click the button (even if the statement will go down with multithreading, but once the driver is used, it will always stop on this statement). I want to ask if this is a bug? What should I do to avoid it?

environment：

- selenium：3.141.0
- firefox：52.9.0（This version will support the showModalDialog command）
- geckodriver：0.15.0

The multi-threaded code is as follows

```py
    PreCarriage_btnVoyageSelector = self.__driver.find_element_by_id(
        'ctl00_ContentPlaceHolder1_UcLegs1_UcPreCarriage_btnVoyageSelector')
    try:
        _thread.start_new_thread(element_click, (PreCarriage_btnVoyageSelector,))
    except TimeoutException:
        pass
    window_handles = self.__driver.window_handles

def element_click(element):
    element.click()
```

Comment: You want to interact with new window ?

Comment: Yes, I need to interact with the new window, but the code cannot execute the switch_to_window line